# How to properly Type an Object of Object with array of keys, without naming all keys in React Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, react-tsx

Hello I'm new to React typescript, and need help fixing some type errors.

Instead of an array of objects, I like to set my data up as object of object with array of keys.

example would be:

```
const teams = {
 team1: {
  name: team1,
  description: 'yada yada'
  },
 team2: {
  name: team2,
  description: 'yada yada,
  },
 keys:[ 'team1', 'team2']
}
```

sometimes on the object the number of 'teams' can change.
I loop through it with:

```
 teams.keys.forEach(key=> teams[key].name)
```

how do I make an interface for this type of object without naming each key for teams?

if this was an array of object I could just do a

```
interface Team {
  name: string,
  description: string
}

interface teams = Array<team>
```

I was hoping there's some way to type it so it know the object teams is made of any number of different `obj<team>` and has a keys array.

```
interface teams = {
  <teams> 
  keys: Array<strings>
}
```

or something along these lines so I don't have to define the name of each key. Super beginner with Typescript any insight would help.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to make this a [mre] without errors unrelated to your question?  What's `team1` and `team2` you've got as the `name` property there? Typos and they should be in quotes?  Or some undeclared values?  Either way it's useful to have something we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs and immediately get to work on it without having to fix issues you're not asking about.

Comment: (See prev comment)  Once you do that... there is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to the relationship you're describing.  You'll need to make it *generic* and then you can have a helper function to infer the type argument.  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wyx2Am).  So instead of `const teams: Teams = { ⋯ }` you write `const teams = asTeams({ ⋯ })` which is a similar number of keystrokes.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W46JvN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining;  If not, what am I missing? Note: this approach doesn't use generics, so it doesn't check for `keys` to include the exact names, just strings